# to extract 3d points from a shp file

Tags: shapefile, python-2.6

I'm trying to work with the shapefile on python,
the file " donnees.shp" contains 3d points
I need to extract attributes from this file
but my code returns an error:

```
>>> import shapefile   
>>> r = shapefile.Reader("donnees.shp") 
>>> r.shapes()[0].shapeType 
... 1  
>>> r.shapes()[0].points    
...[[841001.0, 6399999.0]]
>>> r.shapes()[0].z

... Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
r.shapes()[0].z
AttributeError: _Shape instance has no attribute 'z'
```

what is the nature of this error?
what am I missing?

Comment: That shape has no z value. I would think that the library you're using would have a different method to access it if it is there.  What library are yo using?

Comment: I'm using the shapefile library  :
http://pyshp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shapefile.py

Comment: Given that the `POINTZ` type's code is `11`, and the code you're receiving is `1` or `POINT`, I would anticipate there is a problem with the shapefile.  I just created a shapefile with an explicit set of Z values and had no problems accessing them with the script provided.

Comment: Ok thant you for you answer ... I must apply the script on a 3d shapefile (shapefiles that have a z component.) to be sure that the problem provides from "donnees.shp" ... Now, do you have an example or do you know some sources where I can find that 3d shapefile? thanks

Comment: realy thank you for your help, you're right, there was a problem with the shapefile, I created a new file with z-values and it runs now !

Answer (score 1):

The method you're using to access the values *is* correct according to the [developer's wiki](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/wiki/CreateElevationValues) and the tests I've recently done:

```
import shapefile
r = shapefile.Reader("MyPolyZ")
r.shapes()[0].points
[[-89.0, 33.0], [-90.0, 31.0], [-91.0, 30.0]]
r.shapes()[0].z
[12, 11, 12]
```

To create a 'Z' enabled shapefile, just specify that you want Z values during the creation process:

[image]

[image]

Please be aware of the following procedures for editing Z values in your test cases.

1. Edit mode
2. Select and right click the feature to edit
3. Select 'Edit Verticies'
4. Click the 'Sketch Properties' button
5. Modify the value in the Z column
6. Save an exit edit mode

You can also use steps 1-3 above to determine if your shapefile *actually* has 'Z' values or not.

Once you've done that, make sure you're opening the **correct** shapefile with `shapefile.Reader()`.  If in doubt, use an absolute, rather than relative, path.

(FYI, I was also able to get 'M' values to work with this process as well.